# Getting gridview data in variables and inserting it to database

Tags: asp.net, gridview, foreach

I am making a shopping cart type of thing using grid view user will keep adding item in it after doing it so user will click save i want to get values from all columns of grid view  each row at a time and save it to database.

here is the code for grid view load

```
  protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    product.Item = Item_Drop.SelectedItem.Text;
    product.Quantity = quantity_box.Text;
    int qun =Convert.ToInt32(quantity_box.Text);
    int unitP= Convert.ToInt32(unitPrice_box.Text);
    product.item_Toal = (qun*unitP).ToString();


    list.Add(product);

    temp_gridView.DataSource = list;
    temp_gridView.DataBind();

 }
```

And here is what i am trying to get values

```
    public void Values_from_grid()
{ 
  foreach(temp_gridView row in temp_gridView.Rows)
  {
   for(int i = 0; i < temp_gridView.Columns.Count, i++)
   {
    String header = temp_gridView.Columns[i].HeaderText;
    String cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
   }
   }
 }
```

i am not getting any values in "header" or "cellText" . ..  .

Comment: have you tried GridViewName.rows[0].Cells[0].Text

Comment: yeah i did, basically the control is not going into the for loop. the Columns count always comes 0, but at same time gridView has 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: adil why you need header text ?

Comment: header text contains the column name of the database table in which cellText is going to be inserted.

Comment: i have given the code below please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Answer no need to use

```
GridView.Rows.Count
```

just use a simple int to iterate

```
int i = 0;
foreach(GridViewRow row in  temp_gridView.Rows)
{

box.Item_id = temp_gridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
box.Quantity = temp_gridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
box.Total = temp_gridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
i++;
}
```

Comment: Is this working ? I mean nothing wrong with the code but how you are saving your data ? in this foreach loop every time you are assigning new values to your objects so when your code iterates for second row your objects loses you previous value as you are assigning new value each time .

Comment: Also using column index will get wrong values when you add/delete columns from gridview in future. I suggest you to use template fields in your gridview & use FindControl to find them. Damien.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get header row value .

```
GridViewName.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

Comment: thanks @Raghubar, it worked, actually the main problem was the temp_gridView.Columns.Count was not working thats why the control was not going in to the loop i replaced it with a simple int and now every thing is working fine,,,

Comment: @AdilWaqar No problem was not `temp_gridView.Columns.Count` but your foreach loop.However logic for `temp_gridView.Columns.Count` loop was also wrong.